# query to find more than one name with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my table  i need  more than two names will appear as out put i used count in my query, but name timur has diff company so it cant count as 1  i need count as 2

```
Name    ID  Company Name    CompanyID   Role Name
Ahmed   73  King & Spalding     55      Counsel
Timur   78  Chance CIS Ltd     39       Partner
Timur   78  Clifford LLP       28       Counsel
Rahail  80  Reed Smith ltd     97       Partner
```

out put like this

```
Name    ID  Company Name    CompanyID   Role Name  count
Ahmed   73  King & Spalding     55      Counsel     1
Timur   78  Chance CIS Ltd     39       Partner     2
Timur   78  Clifford LLP       28       Counsel     2
Rahail  80  Reed Smith ltd     97       Partner     1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that name and ID match each other. So in case of duplicated names for different people, I am using ID for partitioning

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  count(*) over (partition by ID) as [count]
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: good it works ,now i don't need the count column instead of that i want name.id,companyname,id ,rolename for those ,i think having should be used but where to use

Comment: You can partition by additional columns by seperating them with comma. example (partition by ID, Name)

Answer (score 0):

Use correlated sub-query:

```
select t.*, (select count(*) from tablename where name = t.name) as count
from tablename t
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or above then you can use a window function to achieve this easily:

```
SELECT
    T.Name,
    T.ID,
    T.CompanyName,
    T.CompanyID,
    T.RoleName,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Name)
FROM
    My_Table T
```

Comment: good it works ,now i don't need the count column instead of that i want name.id,companyname,id ,rolename for those ,i think having should be used but where to use

Comment: If you have another question then you should start it as another question. If you have an underlying problem that you're trying to solve then you should start with that rather than trying to get what you think you need for all of the steps along the way. Someone here probably has a better overall solution to your issue if you don't hide what you're actually trying to solve.